# How to initially not selected any tab in actionbarsherlock?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I have successfully implemented actionsherlock in my project.so here is my code:

```
public class ActiontabActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity   {


    ActionMode mMode;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
            bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

            bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);


            bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            bar.setTitle("Currency Exchange");
            bar.addTab(bar
                    .newTab()
                    .setText("Converter")
                    .setTabListener(
                            new TabListener<Fragment>(this, "Converter",
                                    ConverterTab.class, null)));

            bar.addTab(bar
                    .newTab()
                    .setText("Favorites")
                    .setTabListener(
                            new TabListener1<Fragment>(this, "Favorites",
                                    FavoritesTab.class, null)));
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
            }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("tab", getSupportActionBar()
                .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    }

    public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<ConverterTab> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;




        public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<ConverterTab> clz, Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }




        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();

                if (mFragment == null) {
                    mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(),
                            mArgs);
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    ft.attach(mFragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }


        }




        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if (mFragment != null) {
                    //this segment removes the back history of everything in the tab you are leaving so when you click on the tab again you go back to a fresh start
                    FragmentManager man = mFragment.getFragmentManager();
                    if(man.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) //this check is required to prevent null point exceptions when clicking off of a tab with no history
                        man.popBackStack(man.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); //this pops the stack back to index 0 so you can then detach and then later attach your initial fragment
                    //also it should be noted that if you do popbackstackimmediate here instead of just popbackstack you will see a flash as the gui changes back to the first fragment when the code executes
                    //end
                    ft.detach(mFragment);
                }



        }




        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    }
    public class TabListener1<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<FavoritesTab> mClass;
        private final Bundle mArgs;
        private Fragment mFragment;




        public TabListener1(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<FavoritesTab> clz, Bundle args) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
            mArgs = args;
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
            // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
            // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
            if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }




        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction();

                if (mFragment == null) {
                    mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(),
                            mArgs);
                    ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                    ft.commit();
                } else {
                    ft.attach(mFragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }


        }




        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if (mFragment != null) {
                    //this segment removes the back history of everything in the tab you are leaving so when you click on the tab again you go back to a fresh start
                    FragmentManager man = mFragment.getFragmentManager();
                    if(man.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) //this check is required to prevent null point exceptions when clicking off of a tab with no history
                        man.popBackStack(man.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); //this pops the stack back to index 0 so you can then detach and then later attach your initial fragment
                    //also it should be noted that if you do popbackstackimmediate here instead of just popbackstack you will see a flash as the gui changes back to the first fragment when the code executes
                    //end
                    ft.detach(mFragment);
                }


        }




        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    }
}
```

And i put one button in converter tab and one checkbox in favorites tab.But now i want when i run my app its initially not selected any tab.Just show the main screen and when i pressed any tab it shows it's contents.Because initially i wanted to show other contents when no tab is selected.please tell me how can i do this?Please give me idea that how can i show initially main screen and then when i select any tab it shows its contents.I have attached image of my project:

[image]           [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
bar.addTab(yourTab,false);
```

Like this the tab is still visual selected but the action in the method onTabSelected in listener is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, when you're creating tabs Android should mark any tab as selected. But I have a few ideas.

The first. You can replace the content. Just make a boolean flag and change its value when tab is selected. So when the flag is false(for example) you can show your content for the main screen.

Or the second idea. Just make another main activity with tabs and your content for the main screen. And when any tab is selected just run your activity with real tabs.

Sorry my English. Something can be unclear. So ask me, I will try to explain it more clearly.

Comment: Can you please write some code for example?It will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...
**actionbar.addTab(converterTab,0,false); 
 
actionbar.addTab(favouriteTab,1,false);**